# Is it unnecessary to subclass NSManagedObject in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I know previously you would have to "Editor" > "Create NSManagedObject Subclass" in order to reference your Core Data's entity names in your classes. However I'm given several errors after creating these automatic subclasses.
[image]

[image]

My project runs fine **without** these subclass files, so does Swift 3 not require subclassing to reference entities anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 you don't need to manually create subclasses for `NSManagedObject`s.

By default they are created automatically. But if you want manually create files, set `Codegen` to `Manual/None` in Utilities area for your `testCD.xcdatamodeld`.

From Apple's [What's new in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html):

> ## Xcode automatic subclass generation
>
> Xcode now supports automatic generation of NSManagedObject subclasses in the modeling tool. In the entity inspector:
>
> - Manual/None is the default, and previous behavior; in this case you
>   should implement your own subclass or use NSManagedObject.
> - Category/Extension generates a class extension in a file named like
>   ClassName+CoreDataGeneratedProperties. You need to declare/implement
>   the main class (if in Obj-C, via a header the extension can import
>   named ClassName.h).
> - Class Definition generates subclass files named like ClassName+CoreDataClass as well as the files generated for Category/Extension.
>
> The generated files are placed in DerivedData and rebuilt on the first build after the model is saved. They are also indexed by Xcode, so command-clicking on references and fast-opening by filename works.